# GPU is not recognized on Mac OS high sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensor

I'm trying to run the GPU on Mac OS high Sierra 10.13.6(17G65) right now.
I installed the Nvidia web driver 387.10.10.10.40.105 and CUDA driver 396.148 on my Mac.
But my mac never recognized the GPU.
Can you tell me what is causing this?
I'm Japanese and my English is not very good, so I'm using DeepL to write this article.
I'm not very good at writing, but I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Which GPU are you using?

Comment: I'm using GeForce GTX 1080 ti